# Does the Linked Power feat allow avoiding XP costs for the linked power?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Am I reading the metapsionic feat Linked Power (*Complete Psionic* 62-3) correctly? Can the feat Linked Power be used in such a way to effectively avoid paying the XP cost for the power that's linked to another power?

For example, a psion links to the power *dissipating touch* the power *fusion*. Both powers cost power points, but on the psion's next turn when the *fusion* power manifests, the psion doesn't pay the fusion power's XP cost. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Complete Psionic* is a poorly written, poorly edited book, and Linked Power is quite possibly the worst of them.

Yes, Linked Power allows you to avoid paying XP costs for the linked power, among other things. Yet another reason it should be universally banned.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. I posted an answer with my reasoning.

Comment: @nijineko You know, I originally was going to write that and then I rejected it for some reason. Can’t remember why now. +1 from me anyway, at least until I can remember why I thought that didn’t work.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you can tell from my other posts and comments that my memory doesn't always serve, and I'll be off target on something or another quite frequently. You are quite knowledgeable, and there is probably a good reason why you recall that impression. I'd be very interested to know myself, I hope you recall whatever it was. =D

Answer (score 2):

### No, it does not avoid XP costs

The linked power feat description contains the following text:

> The power that is manifested in this round **is not
>   altered in any way, nor is the linked power
>   that goes off in the next round—however**, you
>   do not need to spend any of your actions or
>   power points next round to manifest the linked power.

The bolded text clearly indicates that other than the text following the "however" clause, that neither power is altered in any way.

The ONLY benefit to Linked Power is exactly what it says: you don't have to spend actions or power points. Therefore, you DO have to pay any XP costs.